# Random walk with equal probability

Tags: java, random

This method randomly increments or decrements (with equal probability) until either -3 or 3 are reached. I'd like to maintain printing the value of `pos` on each iteration, and printing the largest positive number `max` reached at the end of the loop. How can I improve this method using the `Random()` function? I know this sounds pretty ambiguous, but I'd like to know if I can make `rand.nextInt(2) == 0` an easier condition to understand? Any suggestions/improvements are welcome!

```
public static void randomWalk() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int pos = 0;
    int max = 0;
    System.out.println("position = " + pos);
    while (pos > -3 && pos < 3) {
        if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) {
            pos++;
            if (pos > 0) {
                max = pos;
            }
        } else {
            pos--;
        }
        System.out.println("position = " + (int) pos);
            
    }
    System.out.println("max position = " + max);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a minor bug there:

```
        if (pos > 0) {
            max = pos;
        }
```

should test `pos > max` instead.

---

Use

```
max = Math.max(max, pos)
```

to make it shorter.

---

> I'd like to know if I can make rand.nextInt(2) == 0 an easier condition to understand?

Use `rand.nextBoolean()`. For a probability of exactly 50%, it's perfect.

For other probabilities, you can use

```
 rand.nextDouble() < probability
```

---

Another possibility is simply

```
pos += 2 * rand.nextInt(2) - 1;
max = Math.max(max, pos);
```

or

```
pos += rand.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1;
max = Math.max(max, pos);
```

or

```
private static final int[] DELTAS = {+1, -1};

pos += DELTAS[rand.nextInt(DELTAS.length)];
max = Math.max(max, pos);
```

without any conditionals. You may consider it tricky, but it isn't. Obviously, my last solution shouldn't be used for such a simple case.

Concerning the computation of `max` it may be slightly less efficient since it gets executed even if the value decreases. But this doesn't matter unless you need to optimize heavily (your `print` is many orders of magnitude slower than this).

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad there is an easier way to determine probability, and that gives me a different perspective on what a boolean can be, rather than just true or false.

Answer (score -2):

#### Expression

```java
pos > -3 && pos < 3
```

Can be

```java
Math.abs(pos) < 3
```

#### Random choice

Java `Random` had method for sampling boolean values [nextBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean())

#### Bug

This line

```
if (pos > 0) {
```

do not give you

> the largest positive number max reached at the end of the loop

#### Improvement

You don't need to make loop at all. You need random generator that will provide 2 values at each iteration:

- max positive number
- 3 or -3

This can be done using random in following way

```
long sample = Math.abs(rand.nextLong());
int pos, max;
if (sample % 2 == 0) {
    pos = 3;
    max = 3;
} else {
    pos = -3;
    max = int(sample % 3);
}
```

Comment: Concerning `pos`, you're right. Concerning `max`, you're most probably wrong as not all values are equiprobable. Even if they were, you're missing the case `max==3`. Concerning the pair `(pos, max)`, as the probabilities are'nt independent, for example `pos==-3` and `max==2` is rather improbable. And `pos==3` and `max<3` is plain impossible.

Comment: @maaartinus `max` never be 3, read TC's code. I'm so sorry I can't downvote this comment. http://pastebin.com/nnyTp0CK

Comment: Why shouldn't it be 3. First gets `pos` incremented to 3, then `max` computed, and then the loop exits. However, it's all irrelevant, as you can't shortcut the `max` computation to something that trivial. -1 This simply can't work.

Comment: @maaartinus Now I see problem with `max` value. Fixed.

Comment: @maaartinus but I'm not agree that part of uniform distribution can be not uniform. This relate to `max` and `pos` values, as they are both parts of uniformly distributed values of `sample`

Comment: OK, but think a bit more, it's still wrong. Moreover, `rand.nextLong() % 3` can be negative. Moreover, unlike `nextInt(3)` it's not exactly uniform.

Comment: @maaartinus http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong() read carefuly. I'll fix negative values.

Comment: I've read it many times. The problem is that `nextLong()` returns uniformly a number of values which is not a multiple of 3. So your `%3` creates non-uniformity. Try it with a die modulo 5, to see it.

Comment: @maaartinus If `nextLong` is uniformly distributed, lets divide it into many parts with step 3. Each part will be uniformly distributed. If it is not, well, try cover all possible values of pseudo random generator, 1% or 10% is not enough for suggestions.

Comment: You just can't divide 2**64 things in 3 buckets uniformly, just like you can't divide 10 things in 3 buckets uniformly. With that many values, you get pretty close, but it still wrong. That's exactly what gets avoided in the source code of `Random.nextInt`.